# Comparing one dataframe against another with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good Afternoon,

I want to compare dataframe "new" against dataframe "old" to get a new dataframe with data that *only* exists in "new" but *not* old. For example

```
New  Old  Desired Output
---  ---  --------------
1    1    4 
3    2    7
4    3
5    5
7    8
8    9
9    0
```

What I did at first (forgive me, I'm new to this) was:

```
df = pd.concat([new, old])
final = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[:,0].unique())
```

What I failed to realize, of course, is that there are values in 'old' that may not be in 'new' and per my code, those values would also show up in 'final' - which I don't want.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, any help is always appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing `set()` here will help with providing values in `New` and not in `Old`.  Then filter based on the resulting list.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9], columns=['New'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3,5,8,9,0], columns=['Old'])

df1_unique = set(df1['New']) - set(df2['Old'])
final_df= df1[df1['New'].isin(df1_unique)]
final_df.rename(columns = {'New' : 'Desired Output'}, inplace=True)
print(final_df)
```